# Howto download files from WhatsApp Web that is inside my Android WebView App

Tags: java, android, webview, whatsapp

I want to download any file of whatsapp web chat inside my android app

i tried setDownloadListener method to get url and download file but the url is BLOB and i'm unable to download file as i get "unknown protocol: blob". Below is my code

I want to download any file of whatsapp web chat inside my android app

i tried setDownloadListener method to get url and download file but the url is BLOB and i'm unable to download file as i get "unknown protocol: blob". Below is my code

```
package com.example.whatsweb_wascanner;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.UUID;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    MenuItem myMenuitem;
    SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    BlobDownloader blobDownloader;
    public static boolean keyboard_state = true;
    WebView webView;
    MaterialToolbar materialToolbar;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private final Activity activity = this;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
    private PermissionRequest mCurrentPermissionRequest;
    private String mCurrentDownloadRequest = null;


    private static final String STORAGE_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE; // "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE        = 200;
    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE  = 201;
    private static final int AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE   = 202;
    private static final int VIDEO_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE   = 203;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE = 204;
    private static final String CAMERA_PERMISSION = android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA; // "android.permission.CAMERA"
    private static final String AUDIO_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO; // "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
    private static final String[] VIDEO_PERMISSION = {CAMERA_PERMISSION, AUDIO_PERMISSION};



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.loading_screen);
        materialToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarMainActivity);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("whatsappWeb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         sharedPrefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        setSupportActionBar(materialToolbar);

        loadSite();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        },4000);

    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbarmainactivity, menu);
        myMenuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.keyboard);

        if (menu instanceof MenuBuilder) {
            MenuBuilder m = (MenuBuilder) menu;
            m.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
        }

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("whatsappWeb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("IsKeyBoardEnabledOrDisbaled",false))
        {
            keyboard_state = false;
            enableDisableKeyboard(true,myMenuitem);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.keyboard:
                enableDisableKeyboard(keyboard_state,item);
                return true;


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void enableDisableKeyboard(boolean keyboard_stateee, MenuItem item) {


        if(keyboard_stateee)
        {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("IsKeyBoardEnabledOrDisbaled",true).apply();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Keyboard Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_keyboard_hide_24);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

            keyboard_state = false;
         }
        else
        {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("IsKeyBoardEnabledOrDisbaled",false).apply();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Keyboard Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_keyboard_24);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

            keyboard_state = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public void loadSite(){


        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //for wa web
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true); // for camera
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false); //for audio messages

        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); //for html5 app
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setNeedInitialFocus(false);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);



        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
        webView.setInitialScale(200);
        //SET AFTER LOADING SITE BEACUSE OTHERWISE THE SITE LOADS AS MOBILE VERSION
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36";
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
         // webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {

              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloading  file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  /*
                String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
                downloadFile(url, fileName);*/

                mCurrentDownloadRequest = url;
                if(checkPermission(STORAGE_PERMISSION)) {

                    Log.d("SIMRAN has -- ",url);

                    String blobUrl = url;
                    try {
                        downloadFileFromBlobUrl(blobUrl, MainActivity.this);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                 
                } else {
                    requestPermission(STORAGE_PERMISSION);
                }

            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                view.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();

                if (url.contains("whatsapp.com")) {
                    loadSite(); //need to reload

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                return true;
            }

        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {

                //Audio and Video permission when asked by WebView on every Click of Audio/Video Faeture

                if (request.getResources()[0].equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE))
                {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, CAMERA_PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, AUDIO_PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, VIDEO_PERMISSION, VIDEO_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE);
                        mCurrentPermissionRequest = request;
                    }
                    else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, CAMERA_PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{CAMERA_PERMISSION}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE);
                        mCurrentPermissionRequest = request;
                    }
                    else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, AUDIO_PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{AUDIO_PERMISSION}, AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE);
                        mCurrentPermissionRequest = request;
                    } else
                    {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    }

                }
                else if (request.getResources()[0].equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE))
                {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, AUDIO_PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                    else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{AUDIO_PERMISSION}, AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE);
                        mCurrentPermissionRequest = request;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Granting permissions failed "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;
                Intent chooserIntent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED || data.getData() == null)
                {
                    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                else
                {
                   /* Uri result = data.getData();
                    Uri[] results = new Uri[1];
                    results[0] = result;
                    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
*/
                    Uri[] results = null;
                    // Check if the user selected multiple files
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                        results = new Uri[count];
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            results[i] = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                        }
                    } else {
                        results = new Uri[]{data.getData()};
                    }
                    // Pass the selected file(s) back to the WebView
                    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
                    mUploadMessage = null;
                }
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Got activity result with unknown request code " +
                        requestCode + " - " + data.toString());
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
        return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
    }

    private void requestPermission(String permission) {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULTCODE);

    }
    public static void downloadFileFromBlobUrl(String blobUrl, Context context) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(blobUrl);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();

        // Convert the blob URL to a data URL
        String dataUrl = "data:" + connection.getContentType() + ";base64," + Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // Generate a random file name using UUID
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(dataUrl));
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        // Set the destination to the Downloads folder
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please tell value of blobUrl. After that tell value of dataUrl. Also tell which statement causes your error message.

Comment: blobUrl = " blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/70c8e65d-d13b-44be-979e-a0292a1b902d" rest idk. please help. idk what is error. i just want to download the files howto do it. pleas give me code @blackapps